# Load More from Php Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, loops

How is it possible to make load more from array if you scroll to the bottom of the page.
So there are only the first 5 "items" shown and if you scroll to the bottom the next 5 are shown so the browser doesnt chrashes.
My Array:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actvt");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($users as $row) { 
echo $row("username");
}
```

Comment: I would use Ajax request, and basically attach each key from within your object, so you know which object is the last, and have that one pull the last object in the array.

Comment: Alternatively, you can consider using things like server sided DataTables if it is appropriate.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, you can force MySQL to return only a part of the rows in the table: `SELECT * FROM actvt LIMIT 0, 10` (0 is the zero-based row offset and 10 ist the row count).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php

```
function callMore(){
 $last_appt = $_POST['last_result'];
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actvt WHERE date = ".$last_appt." limit = X "); //not sure your table structure , X is how many you want to load
 foreach($statement as $val){
  //Set your gathered results here
 }
 return X //return the results to your ajax call
}
```

js / ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'callMore',
                lastPost : XXXX //Put your last post here
            },
            success : function(msg){
                //Do something with returned data append where ever
            },
            datatype: 'json',
   });
```

From here you will need to detect when you have reached the last post... I recommend doing a detection of when you are at the bottom of the page, if you are using jquery use scrollTop on the last post, to find its Y value, and then window offset with scroll to trigger if you are close to reaching the bottom.. ONce you have reached the bottom, run your ajax function and retrieve the next results.

Answer (score -1):

so you may create sth like a load.php:

```
$start=$_GET["page"]*100;//100 entries
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actvt ");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
$counter=0;
foreach($users as $row) { 
$counter++;
if($counter>$start && $counter <=$start+100){//100 entries
echo $row("username");
}
}
if($counter<$row.length){
echo "<a href='?page=".($page+1)."'>Next Page</a>";
}
```

Now you can call "http://yourpage?page=10"...

The js part is enough to fill another answer...

Comment: You totally missed the mark.. They want to pull in more while scrolling.  Your answer is based on pagination.

Comment: @Cam but thats the first step. the user can step forward by learning js, as this is not a codewriting service...

Comment: the purpose of helpful tips is leading in the right direction.  Giving incorrect code concepts rather than my initial opening comment of use Ajax with key's is a beginning step to answering his question, not glimmering hope of an incorrect solution.  Im not saying you dont know what your talking about, clearly your competent, im saying your solution is not in the right direction. But to each its own.

Comment: @Cam And wheres yours?? ( if yours is better... )